# SQL - Group and Aggregation to calculate ratio with respect to total

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregation

My table looks like below:

**product**     **offer**

Product1        O1

Product1        O1

Product1        O2

Product2        O3

Product2        O4

Where product is a product listed on website and offer is the offer for the product viewed by customer.

What I want is, a query to show percentage of each offer view with respect to total offer views for that product.
So the result should look like below:

**Product**     **Offer**     **ViewPercentage**

Product1          O1         67%

Product1          O2         33%

Product2          O3         50%

Product2          O4         50%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions to compute the view percentage for each offer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product, offer,
     100.0 * (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY product, offer)) / (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY product)) AS ViewPercentage
FROM offers
```

Answer (score 3):

Use aggregation with window functions:

```
SELECT product, offer,
       COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY producct) as ViewRatio
FROM offers
GROUP BY product, offer;
```

Note:  This produces a ratio between 0 and 1 rather than a value between 0 and 100.  You can multiply by 100 if you really want.  And even convert to a string with `%` if that is desired.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 11g onwards `RATIO_TO_REPORT` is an analytic function which can be helpful here.

See here.

```
SELECT product,
  offer,
  round(RATIO_TO_REPORT(cnt) over(partition by  product ) * 100 ) AS "%" 
FROM 
 ( SELECT product,
          offer,
           COUNT(offer) cnt 
   FROM tab
    GROUP BY product, offer);
```